# Data is lost in Mysql docker container after comminting it to a new image?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I pulled a mysql base image from docker hub and run a container from that image and created a database and some tables in that container, and committed the changes to a new image. But when i run a container of my new image, there are no databases that i have created. How to achieve this? I don't want to use mounted volumes because i want to link this container with another container of my application so that it can inset and update into db .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which image you're using but I believe every `Dockerfile` of [official mysql images](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql) has following command:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
```

which means all mysql data goes to volume. From [docker volume docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) they specially mentioned that:

```
> Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image.
```

And this is the root cause you loss your data in newly started container.

For your question:

> How to achieve this?

You can use either [mounted volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume), or create a [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), then run mysql container with option `--volumes-from`. The former links contain step-by-step guide of how to do it.

> I don't want to use mounted volumes because i want to link this container with another container of my application so that it can inset and update into db

I don't know what other concerns you have about mounted volumes, but as far as I can tell, using mounted volumes does not prevent you to link containers.

Hope this helps you.